# Django Rest Framework to return desired results from two models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (customer, movie) and I would like to return (movie_name, customer_name, id) when I hit the URL (api/customer/1) and when I hit the URL (api/customer/1/movies) just wanted the movie names alone. How can we achieve this ?

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Movie(models.Model):
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/customers/$', CustomerSerializer.as_view(), name='customers'),
]
```

**Note:**

- At the moment, when I hit the URL (api/customers) it returns the id, name of all the customers. Now, I would like to know, when I hit the URL (api/customer/1) how to list the same information along with movie names and when I hit the URL (api/customer/1/movies) how to just return the movie names alone?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write two urls for this purpose but you can do this with one view and serializer like this

Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/customers/<int:id>/', CustomerMovieView.as_view(check=True)),
    path('api/customers/<int:id>/movies/', CustomerMovieView.as_view(check=False)),
]
```

Views and Serializers

```
from rest_framework import generics, response, serializer


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     customer_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
     def get_customer_name(self, instance):
         return instance.customer.name

     class Mete:
         model = Movie
         fields = '__all__'

     def to_representation(self, instance):
         data = super().to_representation(instance)
         if not self.context('check'):
             data.pop('customer_name', None)
             data.pop('customer', None)
         return data


class CustomerMovieView(generics.GenericAPIView):
     serializer_class = MovieSerializer
     check = True
     
     def get_serializer_context(self):
         context = super().get_serializer_context()
         context.update({'check': self.check})
         return context

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         id = kwargs.get('id')
         movie = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
         serialized = self.get_serializer(movie)
         return response.Respoonse(serialized.data)
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting "AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.generics' has no attribute 'GenericApiView'" error message. Also can explain me what you are referring here as "ViewSerializer" ?

Comment: It was a spelling mistake. Check now.

Comment: Thanks for helping.. But few things are bit confusing as I am new to django.. As I have asked earlier, what you are referring here as ViewSerializer? Because I am getting "NameError: name 'ViewSerializer' is not defined"

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but what is this line "customer_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()" referring to?

Comment: Bit Confused, can you please rename with my actual serializer names given in my original questions?

Comment: It was an example therefore I used general names. Check now. I have updated name.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield
In serializermethodfield, you define custom method to get a field value as it is not directly in model for which you have make serializer.

Comment: Thanks, understood. But with this code, I am getting "prm.models.Movie.DoesNotExist: Movie matching query does not exist."

Comment: In order to serialize, you need to provide some data to your serializer. I told you this is example. You are hitting with data which is not in your database.